# Null Object Reference on setOnClickListner Method

Tags: java, android

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kritisharan.tictactoe/com.example.kritisharan.tictactoe.starter_activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Code in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

    FloatingActionButton reset = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.reset);

    reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

XML Code in activity_main.xml

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/reset"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="10sp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"/>
```

Don't know why it is considering a null reference. Searched all the solutions but couldn't find anything that works. Please help.

Comment: Show content_main.xml that you're inflating, not activity_main.xml.

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class)); both in main activity check it

Comment: You don't understand.  In the onCreate you show, it's inflating content_main.xml.  But in your description after that, you say you are showing activity_main.xml.  That's not the same thing.

Comment: @Doug I am just using tools in the content_main.xml this way:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.kritisharan.tictactoe.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

Comment: @Doug Thanks a tonne, I can't believe I made such a stupid error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content_main.xml you're inflating does not contain a view with id `reset` as you're trying to find in onCreate().  Perhaps you are inflating the wrong XML layout.  It looks like you want activity_main.xml instead.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line of code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
```

to:   `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Answer (score 1):

Change your `OnCreate()` method with this one.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

.......

}
```

Try this.